# How to find angle between two vectors given only the magnitudes and the difference in magnitudes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

This is a physics first year problem, the same problem has been posted on the [Math Stack Exchange website](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367442/how-do-you-find-the-angle-between-two-vectors-if-the-only-thing-you-know-is-thei#comment6929833_3367442), but the answer given there is beyond the scope of what is taught in my course! For now, all my teacher has taught me are the cosine law and just the laws of vectors in general.

Here is the problem,

> Vector $\vec B$ is 5.0 cm long and vector $\vec A$ is 4.0 cm long. Find the angle, in degrees, between these two vectors when |$\vec A$ + $\vec B$| = 3.0 cm and |$\vec A$ - $\vec B$| = 3.0 cm.

I really don't know where to start with this one, and have been stuck for a hot minute now... any help would be appreciated, and it would really help me get the concept of vectors for this course!

Comment: Try writing the vectors in terms of $i$ and $j$ basis vectors, and using the distance formula. It might not be the most efficient, but it works.

Comment: The wording in your title question is misleading. You are not given the difference in magnitudes. You are given the magnitudes of the sums and differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|\vec{A}+\vec{B}|=|(x+x')i + (y+y')j|=\sqrt{(x+x')^2+(y+y')^2}=3\implies(x+x')^2+(y+y')^2=9$$

$$|\vec{A}-\vec{B}|=|(x-x')i + (y-y')j|=\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2}=3\implies(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2=9$$

$$|\vec{A}|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=4 \implies x^2+y^2=16$$

$$|\vec{B}|=\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}=4 \implies x'^2+y'^2=25$$

You have lots of equations. Use them to get $x,x',y,y'$ and you can use the dot product formula to get the angle.

---

If you want the solution:
$$(x+x')^2+(y+y')^2=9 \implies x^2+2xx'+x'^2+y^2+2yy'+y'^2=9 \implies 2xx'+2yy'+16+25=9\implies 2(xx'+yy')=-32\implies xx'+yy'=-16$$

This is exactly the dot product formula, so:

$$\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}=-16=|A||B|\cos(\theta)=20\cos(\theta)\implies \cos(\theta)=-4/5$$
so
$$\theta = 2.498 \text{  or  } \theta = -2.498$$

Note that as Jensen Paull said, the problem is impossible with the condition:

$$|\vec{A}-\vec{B}|=3$$

Without it you would get to my solution.

Comment: I'm confused as to why u added x' and y'?

Comment: Check the completed answer. I edited the answer.

Comment: What about the angle theta from the other equation? The differences between the vectors.

Comment: @jensen paull. There is something weird about it. It gives contradictory results that I think might be a mistake. If I remember correctly, the only way the magnitude of the sum and difference to be equal is to have them perpendicular to each other, which is certainly not the case, because they don't form a Pythagorean triangle.

Comment: I've made a follow up question outlining this question again in a  clearer form mathematically, I doubt there is a solution to this question .

Comment: I just drew the vectors on GeoGebra. The sum and magnitude of each vector are correct. Only the difference is different. The magnitude of the difference should've been 8.5.

Comment: The problem is IMPOSSIBLE.

Answer (score 1):

$|\vec A+\vec B|^2=(\vec A+\vec B)\cdot (\vec A+\vec B)=\vec A\cdot \vec A + 2(\vec A\cdot \vec B)+\vec B\cdot \vec B=|\vec A|^2+2(\vec A\cdot \vec B)+|\vec B|^2$

$|\vec A-\vec B|^2=(\vec A-\vec B)\cdot (\vec A-\vec B)=\vec A\cdot \vec A - 2(\vec A\cdot \vec B)+\vec B\cdot \vec B=|\vec A|^2-2(\vec A\cdot \vec B)+|\vec B|^2$

Subtract the equations to get:

$|\vec A+\vec B|^2-|\vec A-\vec B|^2=4(\vec A\cdot \vec B)$

So you can work out what the dot product of $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ is, which should help.

As an aside, the second equation is a vector version of the cosine rule for triangles. If vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are two sides of a triangle, the third side $\vec c=\vec a-\vec b$. The cosine rule for this triangle says: $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\,\mathrm{cos}\,C$, Where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the magnitudes of the vectors, and the last term on the right is just two times the dot product of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$. If the dot product is zero, then you have a right-angled triangle, and this reduces to Pythagoras' Theorem.

Comment: Your answer say that the angle is 90 degrees however that isn't the only condition .substituting this back into one of your 2 equations yields a contradiction. It's not possible

Comment: Hmm. Yes, I suspect the intention was that this was supposed to be a 3-4-5 right-angled triangle, and the question-setter got the sides mixed up. Use $|\vec A|=3$, $|\vec B|=4$ and $|\vec A+\vec B|=|\vec A-\vec B|=5$.

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the dot product of each one (the difference and sumed terms) with itself (basically, square them) and then you can find the cosine of the angle between them.

Comment: I think this doesn't answer the question. How can he square the vectors if he doesn't have them? He has the magnitude of the sum and difference.

Comment: I said square the |A + B| and |A-B| terms, not the A and B themselves!

Comment: I also edited my answer to be more clear about the correct solution.

Comment: what do you mean when you say the dot product of "each one"?

Answer (score 0):

[Follow up, given differences and addition of vectors, find angle inbetween](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/718603/follow-up-given-differences-and-addition-of-vectors-find-angle-inbetween)

This problem is impossible since

$$\cos(\theta) = u$$
$$\cos(\theta) = - u$$

Solutions are:

$$u=0, \cos(\theta) = 0$$

Which is not valid on this problem.

Comment: Yes, I would rather try to remove the equality  |A - B| = 3.0 cm from the question